# why alarmMgr.SetAlarmClock() is not setting alarm accurately?

Tags: android, kotlin

apologies if this is a simple answer that I do not know. I am trying to set an alarm with alarm managers setAlarmClock(). My alarm goes off on the proper time, but it is random throughout the minute I set it at. For example, if I set it at 8:30, it will go off at 8:30, but it is random throughout the minute that it goes off. How do I get it to go off right as it turns 8:30.

```
val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31)
        }


var trig: AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo = 
    AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, alarmIntent)
        alarmMgr?.setAlarmClock(
            trig,
            alarmIntent
        )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936552/15005298
try this link it will help you

Comment: https://github.com/orbitalsonic/Daily-Repeating-Notification-Android-Kotlin
here source code try it

Comment: thanks much, I was able to get help from that source code. It turns out I had to set the seconds of the calendar to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the calender seconds to zero to get it to work right at the start of the minute.

```
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
```